# Listing of numbers within a range in reverse order

Tags: vb.net

I have two text boxes and one button and a list box
I would like to enter two ranges of values on each text box, when I click the button all the value in between the range that I have given in text boxes should show in List box

I would like to get the code in Vb.net

eg: 100 to 200

should show :200,199,198....100

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    For i As Integer = CInt(txt1.Text) To CInt(tx2.Text) Step -1 ' for print it in reverse order
        ListBox1.Items.Add(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one liner:

```
ListBox1.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(100, 101).Reverse.ToList
```

You will have to substitute 100 with the number from where you want to begin counting. And 101 with number of items you want in the series; so basically the difference of FROM and TO, plus ONE.

Comment: your range is `100,101` then how it prints numbers between `100` and `200` ?

Comment: @LOsunG The first parameter defines the start, the second one the number of elements; so `Enumerable.Range(100, 101)` yields 100, 101, 102, 103, ..., 200.

Comment: @ sloth :  thanks for the information am not familiar with `Enumerable` that's why i asked for a clarification. thanks a lot, +1 for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick suggestion, put code below in a button event:

**VB.NET:**

```
Dim low As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(txtLow.Text)
Dim high As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(txtHigh.Text)
Dim numbers As New List(Of Integer)()
For i As Integer = low To high - 1
    numbers.Add(i)
Next
listBox1.DataSource = numbers
```

**C#:**

```
int low = Convert.ToInt32(txtLow.Text);
int high = Convert.ToInt32(txtHigh.Text);
List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
for(int i = low; i < high; i++)
{
    numbers.Add(i);
}
listBox1.DataSource = numbers;
```

Remeber to add validation.

Comment: @LOsunG Same to you:)